# Server 2012, Attempted to Install Certificate Services, now Win-RM is broken

Tags: windows-server-2012, exchange-2010, ad-certificate-services, winrm

I have two exchange servers, one running Exchange 2007 and one Exchange 2010. On the Exchange 2010 I attempted to install a AD-Certificate role but after installing the role I am unable to run the Post-Deployment Wizard. When the wizard is opened I recieve the error:

> Failed to open runspace pool. The Server Manager WinRM plug-in might be corrupt or missing.

Other Symptoms that occurred at this time include problems with the Server Manager and Exchange Management consoles and problems with Powershell. While the server seems to be serving mail properly I cannot manage the server otherwise.

**Troubleshooting**

I have attempted the following:

- Run *WinRM quickconfig* which shows the service is running and setup
  for management.
- Restored WinRM settings: *winrm invoke restore
  winrm/config @{}*
- Restored WinRM plugin settings: *winrm invoke
  restore winrm/config/plugin @{}*
- Add "127.0.0.1" and "::1" to the IP
  listen list
- Disabled the firewall (opened the ports, service still
  running).
- Installed Windows Management 4.0 Framework
- Ensured the Windows Remote Management (WS-Management) service is running.

I am quickly running out of internet articles on this topic. I don't know what WinRM is supposed to look like in IIS. Should the WinRM IIS extension appear as one of the Application Pools?

I am still receiving the following errors.

**Server Manager Error:**

> Manageability: Online-Cannot get event data

**Exchange Console Error:**

> The following error occurred while attempting to connect to the specified Exchange server '*servername*'.
>
> The attempt to connect to http://*servername*/Powershell using "Kerberos" authentication failed: connecting to remote server *servername*.*domain*.net failed with the following error message: The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig". For more information see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

**Powershell Error (log)**

> Runspace Id: c5fb6a25-b76d-4730-8bd0-3fa2fd2f3093 Pipeline Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. WSMan reported an error with error code: -2144108485.
>
> Error message: Connecting to remote server  failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. Cannot find the Microsoft.Windows.ServerManagerWorkflows session configuration in the WSMan: drive on the  computer. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

**Windows Remote Management Error (log)**

> WSMan operation CreateShell failed, error code 2150858811